# windows 8 mongodb locked file, bad shut down

Tags: mongodb

I just got mongo running yesterday, I entered  C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe, then bought up another command prompt and entered the same thing again, and it was working fine. I ended up shutting it down wrong and now im getting  unable to create/open lock file: data/db/mongod/lock because it is being used by another process. I have tried all of what im seeing but getting not recognized errors. It was a little test db, so i want to just get rid of it so i can open mongo again. I deleted the file.lock from my db file as well, but not sure it worked seems like it left and was back again, but it might just be me.

I know this is a super easy problem, just not getting it. Where should i be entering these command, im following the instructions, but i know im not inputing them in the right place because none of them work at all. I tried just inputting them, in C, in C: data/db, i entered C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe left it open and opened another command prompt and enter everything in there to. I can't just reset mongodb? Does anyone know what I'm missing maybe it's i have no windows knowledge at all, i'm trying to use it because i know javascript a little php/sql and i'm trying to learn node.js when i had it working in the shell it was great, but with this set up stuff i'm lost. I'm understanding everything there saying but just not where to do it i think.

Someone please lol, i just uninstalled mongodb and reinstalled and same problem.

```
mongod --repair (is not recognized as internal, or external command)
db.repairDatabase(same,,is not recognized as internal, or external command);
\data\db\mongod.lock (asks how i want to open it)
```

This is my set up, i think mongod is the problem, but can't get rid of it.

```
Computer>Windows>data>db

_tmp
joural
local
local.ns
mongod      locked file
```

edit*** not sure if i removed the lock or not but i got it to work. I should have wrote down how i did it but pretty sure this was it.

open a command prompt cd\ enter it cd mongodb\bin enter it open another command cd\ enter it cd mongoDb\bin enter it. in the first command enter mongod then in the other one enter mongo. Don't know if this is right way, but i got me to be able to play with mongodb like i wanted.

Comment: You may find it easier to setup [MongoDB as a Windows service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service). It sounds like you may have closed `mongod.exe` unexpectedly (in which case it should recover when you restart) or perhaps even had another copy of `mongod.exe` running. It's a bit hard to tell from your problem description, but if you're just getting started with learning MongoDB a clean install might be less hassle :).

Answer (score 0):

try to remove mongod.lock and journal, then restart.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal - are you sure you commented on the right answer? I don't see link-only; I see a suggestion to remove the lock file and journal (and no edits to the answer).

Comment: @Amit Agrawal my goal was to get it to work, I don't know if i removed it, but i got it to work. Now i am accessing by cd\... cd mongoDB\bin...    then another window cd\... monogdb\bin... then in first command prompt mongod enter secound one mongo enter

Comment: You definitely don't want to remove the lock and journal files: the whole purpose of those is for consistent recovery in the event of improper shutdown.